# D3 Filtering and Aggregates in a Line Chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, aggregate, data-visualization

I am new to D3.js - what I would like to do is work on data formatted in this way to create a line graph.

[image: data graph showing password gender and timestamps on top, and data below]

Time1,2,3,4,5 etc represent seconds of video, and the score represents the users happiness with that part of the video.

I'd like to create a graph that represents the mean/average for Males and another for Females.
i.e. Point1 for females would be 3.33 or [(3+4+3)/3], Point2 would be 4.33 [(5+5+3)/3].

I've read up on the filter AND aggregate commands and examples but having trouble putting it all together for my line graph. **How would I go about creating such an 'aggregate line graph' that is based on multiple columns.**

NOTE: The 'final product' will have MANY columns like gender for 'on the fly' aggregation so pre-calculation isn't an option. If there's an example/tutorial/anything that can help, please let me know.

Comment: I don't really see a question in your post. Maybe you could elaborate on what exactly you're having trouble with?

Comment: Thx. I Have editted and bolded the specific question.